# jQuery Countdown from certain time

Tags: jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

Does anyone know how to set a countdown timer from a certain time. I have this code so far. But it counts down from midnight to midnight. I'd like it to countdown from 11am to 11am.

```
   <script>
      setInterval(function time() {
      var d = new Date();
      var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
      var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
      if ((min + '').length == 1) {
      min = '0' + min;
      }
      var sec = 59 - d.getSeconds();
      if ((sec + '').length == 1) {
      sec = '0' + sec;
      }
      jQuery('#the-final-countdown p').html(hours + ':' + min + ':' +  sec)
      }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below You can write any time you want to count down and the JS code do the job.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=9b10f170c556944a5fdb19700bef6840)**

HTML

```
<input id="hr" placeholder="hr" type="text">
<input id="mn" placeholder="mn" type="text">
<input id="sc" placeholder="sc" type="text">
<button id="start">
  Start
</button>
<br>
<br>
<span id="timerhr"></span>:<span id="timermn"></span>:<span id="timersc"></span>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hr;
  var mn;
  var sc;
  var thr;
  var tmn;
  var tsc;
  $('#start').click(function(){
    hr = $('#hr').val();
    mn = $('#mn').val();
    sc = $('#sc').val();
    if(hr  == ""){
      hr = 0;
    }
    if(mn  == ""){
      mn = 0;
    }
    if(sc  == ""){
      sc = 0;
    }
    parseInt(hr);
    parseInt(mn);
    parseInt(sc);

    hr = hr*3600;
    mn = mn*60
    sc = hr + mn + sc;
    start(sc);
  });
});
function start(e){
  var interv = setInterval(function(){
  thr = e/3600;
  thr = Math.floor(thr);
  $('#timerhr').text(thr);
  tmn = (e%3600)/60;
  tmn = Math.floor(tmn);
  $('#timermn').text(tmn);
  tsc = e-(thr*3600+tmn*60);
  $('#timersc').text(tsc);
  e--;
  if(e < 0){
    clearInterval(interv);
  }
  },1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but is there any way of this being automatic? So i don't have to input a time, it will just countdown from 11am every day and when it hits 11am the next day it will automatically start again.

Comment: I removed inputs and you will be defining hr, mn, sc variables by yourself and when you click start it will automaticly start countdown and when reach 0 it will start again. You will set hr to 24, mn:0 and sc:0 then start it at 11:00 am. thats all. You can edit the code for your need im just providing you the idea of customized count down timer. http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=256b890ab8c62968bb12de5c0897db97

Comment: Hi Just realised. The timer resets when the page loads. How can I get the count down timer to: Countdown 24 hours starting from 11am, reset when it gets to 00:00, be automatic so it does not reset on page load or need a button to start it off?

Comment: In that you need to create something on server-side i belive becauyse js only works in client-side and when client opens the page the counter starts. What you are asking now is whole different story.